# Is there a way to put the a Napili Community in Maintenance Mode?

Tags: customer-community, napili

We are updating some object relationships, and have to run a couple of scripts to reassign some lookups. This a purely custom Lightning Component Community.

Is there an easy way to put the whole site into a state that will only display a Maintenance Page, if a user tries to access the site?  Ive seen a few mention of disabling/freezing users, or reassigning Profiles, but I figured there may be a built in setting.

We could deactivate the Site I guess, but all I could get to show up is a blank page. Or maybe user redirects... but, I hope Im missing a simple setting.

Comment: This is bad. Why arent you doing this in a sandbox?

Comment: All of this has rolled through Dev Sandbox-> QA Sandbox-> UAT Full Sandbox -> (Now to Prod). Everything should go smoothly and quickly. I would just like to be able to take the community down outside of business hours if needed.

Comment: I guess you can setup redirect rules and then remove them once you are done

Comment: check this out .https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47283/sites-while-in-maintenance-mode-custom-maintenance-pages-do-not-display

Comment: did you try updating the inactive site home page in sites?

Comment: I did set the Inactive Site Home Page to the InMaintenance page, and the Preview showed the correct page.  But I still got a blank (all white) page when I went to the inactive site.  This is in my Sandbox, but I would think it should work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this may not work for everyone, but this got me what I wanted.  In hindsight, Im not sure why this wasnt more obvious for me.

In the Community Builder (Login & Registration -> Login -> Choose Login Page), we set the Login page to a custom VF Page we created for maintenance. We could have used the existing InMaintenance page as well.

Thanks for all the other suggestions